# HTML5 Video when scrolling, playing but not at right scroll point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a webpage with 5 different videos as full screen backgrounds. Which work fine when just left to loop.

I've been trying to get it to play once each individual section is scrolled over and then stop when scrolled passed.

I'm using this code for scrolling.

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");

function checkScroll() {

    for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

        var video = videos[i];

        var x = video.offsetLeft, y = video.offsetTop, w = video.offsetWidth, h = video.offsetHeight, r = x + w, //right
        b = y + h, //bottom
        visibleX, visibleY, visible;

        visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
        visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));

        visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);

        if (visible > fraction) {
            video.play();
        } else {
            video.pause();
        }

    }

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);
```

And this is my website with how far I've got.

anorris.co.uk/testing

I'm really quite confused as to why It's only playing when its at the top?